# MS Access Database tables comparison

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to compare three MS Access tables for any given field. For example, I have a `Main Table`, which holds the record for school children. It has the fields `Student ID` and `Name`. Then there are 3 sub-tables schools, but they have some data discrepancy. So lets call these schools, `A`, `B` and `C`. These schools have somehow mixed up `Student ID` with `Name`, so I need a way to return any `Student ID`, which has a mismatch for `Name`. The `Main table` has `student ID` as the `PKey`, and the other; A, B & C have `student ID` as `PKey` as well. But the problem is that when I build relationships in Access, it only returns IDs that are common in all 3 tables - `INNER JOIN`. I need an efficient way to match schools, A -> B & A -> C and concatenate the results. I think JOINING each of these in pairs might take far too long. Please let me know if you have any other alternatives.

Comment: You tag MySQL, but say MS Access... Which one are you using?

Comment: Your problem is complicated. Shouldn't you add some simple (plaintext) tables for easier understanding instead of wall of text? I tried to make your text a little bit shorter so that people don't give up halfway reading.

Comment: Can you add some sample records and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

So, you have two problems:

1. You have bad data that needs to be fixed Student_ID and NAme mixed
   up
2. Your schema is not good.

**Addressing the data issue:**

If your student_ids are all numeric, you could try something like:

```
UPDATE subA SET student_id = [name], [name]=student_id WHERE isnumeric([name]);
```

And repeat for the other mixed up sub tables.

**Addressing the schema issue:**

You have three "Subtables" one for each school. These three tables should be a single table, and "School" should be a field in that table. So your data looks something like:

```
+--------+------------+---------+
| School | Student_Id |  Name   |
+--------+------------+---------+
| A      |          1 | John    |
| A      |          2 | Jasmine |
| B      |          3 | Fred    |
| C      |          5 | Harold  |
| C      |          6 | Donna   |
+--------+------------+---------+
```

This way you only join in a single table, and your data only grows in rows as new schools are brought into your database.

Second, if I'm reading your question correctly, you have both `student_id` and `name` in the `main` table as well as the three sub-tables? It seems like you should only keep these in a single table, maybe named `student`.

Lastly, you can combine the three subtables into a single view that will make it 9000% (guesstimate) easier to join for future queries, using a UNION query:

```
SELECT 'A' as school, student_id, name FROM subA
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', student_id, name FROM subB
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', student_id, name FROM subC
```

This will stack all three tables on top of each other and give you a schema similar to the example above. You can join to your `main` table like:

```
SELECT *
FROM mainTable 
    INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT 'A' as school, student_id, name FROM subA
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'B', student_id, name FROM subB
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'C', student_id, name FROM subC
        ) AS subs ON
        mainTable.student_id = subs.student_id
```